# Dynamic header name refresh with Ag-Grid

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I have a "select" column and I want to have the total of the current selected rows in the header name.

I am using `headerValueGetter` but the value is not refreshed when a new row is selected.

```
// in my colDef
headerValueGetter: params => `(${this.totalSelected})`

// methods
onSelectionChanged(event) {
  this.totalSelected = event.api.getSelectedNodes().length
},
```

`totalSelected` is a property of my Vue component and its value is updated when a new row is selected.

Any ideas how to accomplish this ?

[image]

Comment: reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try refreshing the header manually in your selectionChanged-event:

```
onSelectionChanged(event) {
  this.totalSelected = event.api.getSelectedNodes().length;
  gridOption.api.refreshHeader();
},
```